# Having problem with upload class depending on ImageMagick tool

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, image-upload

Hello I am dealing with the upload class, I want to upload the images to the specified directories but it doesn't work. I have Installed the Imagick extension and ImageMagick as well and I checked for the '/urs/bin/convert' path and it exists.
Here is the project.

/test/index.php:

```
> <?php
>     require_once ('lib/config.php');
>     require_once ('classes/upload.php');
>     require_once ('classes/image.php');
> 
>     if (extension_loaded('imagick')){
>         echo 'imagick installed <br />';
>     }
>     $message = null;
>     if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
>         $upload = new Upload();
>         $upload->_field_name = 'image';
>         $upload->_path = IMAGES_PATH;
>         $upload->_new_file_name = str_replace(" ", "-", $_POST['title']) . '.' . date('ymdhis');
>         if($upload->isValid() && !empty($_POST['title'])) {
>             if($upload->send()) {
>                 //create thumbnail
>                 image::crop(
>                     IMAGES_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $upload->_new_name,
>                     IMAGES_THUMBNAIL_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $upload->_new_name,
>                     IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_WIDTH,
>                     IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT
>                 );
>                 //create large
>                 image::resize(
>                     IMAGES_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $upload->_new_name,
>                     IMAGES_LARGE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $upload->_new_name,
>                     IMAGE_LARGE_LENGTH
>                 );
>                 $message = 'Image Uploaded successfully';
>             }
>         } else {
>                 $out = array();
>                 if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
>                     $out[] = 'Provide a title';
>                 }
>                 $image = $upload->getErrorMessage();
>                 if (!empty($image)) {
>                     $out[] = $image;
>                 }
>                 $message  = '<p class="warning">';
>                 $message .= implode('<br />', $out);
>                 $message .= '</p>';
>         }
>     }
>     ?>
>     <!DOCTYPE html>
>     <html>
>     <style>
>         input[type=text], input[type=file], select {
>             width: 100%;
>             padding: 12px 20px;
>             margin: 8px 0;
>             display: inline-block;
>             border: 1px solid #ccc;
>             border-radius: 4px;
>             box-sizing: border-box;
>         }
> 
>         input[type=submit] {
>             width: 100%;
>             background-color: #4CAF50;
>             color: white;
>             padding: 14px 20px;
>             margin: 8px 0;
>             border: none;
>             border-radius: 4px;
>             cursor: pointer;
>         }
> 
>         input[type=submit]:hover {
>             background-color: #45a049;
>         }
> 
>         div {
>             border-radius: 5px;
>             background-color: #f2f2f2;
>             padding: 20px;
>         }
>     </style>
>     <body>
>     <h3><?php echo $message ?></h3>
>     <div>
>         <form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" data-multi-step>
>             <label for="Title">Title</label>
>             <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title..">
> 
>             <label for="Image">Image</label>
>             <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif">
> 
>             <input type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit">
>         </form>
>     </div>
> 
>     </body>
>     </html>

/test/lib/config.php
>   <?php
> 
>     defined('DS') || define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
> 
>     /* Root path */
>     defined('ROOT_PATH') || define('ROOT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . DS . '..' . DS));
> 
>     /* Images Directory */
>     defined('IMAGES_DIR') || define('IMAGES_DIR', 'images');
> 
>     /* Thumbnail Directory */
>     defined('IMAGES_THUMBNAIL_DIR') || define('IMAGES_THUMBNAIL_DIR', IMAGES_DIR . DS . 'thumbnail');
> 
>     /* Large Directory */
>     defined('IMAGES_LARGE_DIR') || define('IMAGES_LARGE_DIR', IMAGES_DIR . DS . 'large');
> 
>     /* Images path */
>     defined('IMAGES_PATH') || define('IMAGES_PATH', ROOT_PATH . DS . IMAGES_DIR);
> 
>     /* thumbnail path */
>     defined('IMAGES_THUMBNAIL_PATH') || define('IMAGES_THUMBNAIL_PATH', ROOT_PATH . DS .
> IMAGES_THUMBNAIL_DIR);
> 
>     /* Large path */
>     defined('IMAGES_LARGE_PATH') || define('IMAGES_LARGE_PATH', ROOT_PATH . DS . IMAGES_LARGE_DIR);
> 
>     defined('IMAGE_LARGE_LENGTH') || define('IMAGE_LARGE_LENGTH', 600);
>     defined('IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_WIDTH') || define('IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_WIDTH', 108);
>     defined('IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT') || define('IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT', 75);
>     defined('IMAGE_PER_PAGE') || define('IMAGE_PER_PAGE', 10);
> 
>     var_dump(IMAGES_LARGE_PATH);

/test/classes/image.php
> 
> <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
> 
> <!-- language: lang-html -->
> 
>     <?php
> 
>     class Image {
> 
>         public static $_path = '/usr/bin/convert';
> 
>         public static function crop($from = null, $to = null, $width = 100, $height = 100) {
>             if(is_file($from)) {
>                 $to = !empty($to) ? $to : $from;
>                 $imginfo = getimagesize($from);
>                 $original_w = $imginfo[0];
>                 $original_h = $imginfo[1];
>                 $longest_new = $width > $height ? $width : $height;
>                 $longest_original = $original_w > $original_h ? $original_w : $original_h;
>                 if($longest_original > $longest_new) {
>                     $command = self::$_path . " {$from} -resize {$longest_new}x{$longest_new}^ -gravity Center -crop
> {$width}x{$height}+0+0 {$to}";
>                 } else {
>                     $command = self::$_path . " {$from} -gravity Center -crop {$width}x{$height}+0+0 {$to}";
>                 }
>                 exec($command);
>             }
>         }
> 
>         public static function resize($from = null, $to = null, $width = 600) {
>             if(is_file($from)) {
>                 $to = !empty($to) ? $to : $from;
>                 $imginfo = getimagesize($from);
>                 $original_w = $imginfo[0];
>                 $original_h = $imginfo[1];
>                 $longest_original = $original_w > $original_h ? $original_w : $original_h;
>                 if($longest_original > $width) {
>                     $command = self::$_path . " {$from} -resize {$width}x{$width}\> {$to}";
>                     exec($command);
>                 } else {
>                     copy($from, $to);
>                 }
> 
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
```

/test/classes/upload.php

```
>     <?php
> 
>     class Upload {
> 
>         /* file name */
>         public $_field_name = 'image';
>         /* New file name */
>         public $_new_file_name;
>         /* New file name ready to upload */
>         public $_new_name;
>         /* Max file size 2MB */
>         public $_file_size = 8097152;
>         /* allowed extensions */
>         public $_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
>         /* extension of the file */
>         public $_extension;
>         /* Directory Path */
>         public $_path;
>         /* Validation */
>         private $_valid = false;
>         /* error */
>         public $_error;
>         /* array of error message */
>         public $_validation = array(
>             'file_size' => 'The uploaded file exceeds the maximum file size of 8MB',
>             'extension' => 'Wrong file format',
>             'name'      => 'File with this name already exists',
>             1           => 'The uploaded file exceeds the maximum file size',
>             2           => 'The uploaded file exceeds the maximum file size',
>             3           => 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded',
>             4           => 'No file was selected',
>             6           => 'Missing a temporary folder',
>             7           => 'Failed to write file to disk',
>             8           => 'Problem with the extension'
>         );
> 
> 
>         public function isValid() {
>             if(!empty($_FILES)){
>                 $this->_error = $_FILES[$this->_field_name]['error'];
>                 $this->_valid = true;
>                 if($this->_error === 0){
> 
>                     if(!$this->checkExtension()) {
>                         return false;
>                     }
> 
>                     if(!$this->checkSize()){
>                         return false;
>                     }
>                     if(!$this->checkName()){
>                         return false;
>                     }
>                     return true;
>                 }
>                 return false;
>             }
>             return false;
>         }
> 
>         private function checkExtension() {
>             $this->_extension = self::getExtension($_FILES[$this->_field_name]['name']);
>             if(!in_array($this->_extension, $this->_extensions)) {
>                 $this->_error = 'extension';
>                 return false;
>             }
>             return true;
>         }
> 
>         public static function getExtension($file_name = null) {
>             if (!empty($file_name)) {
>                 $file = explode('.', $file_name);
>                 if(!empty($file)){
>                     return array_pop($file);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
> 
>         private function checkSize() {
>             if($_FILES[$this->_field_name]['size'] > $this->_file_size) {
>                 $this->_error = 'file_size';
>                 return false;
>             }
>             return true;
>         }
> 
>         private function checkName() {
>             if(!empty($this->_new_file_name)) {
>                 $this->_new_name = $this->_new_file_name. '.' . $this->_extension;
>             } else { 
>                 $this->_new_name = $_FILES[$this->_field_name]['name'];
>             }
>             if(is_file($this->_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->_new_name)) {
>                 $this->_error = 'name';
>                 return false;
>             }
>             return true;
>         }
> 
>         public function send() {
>             if($this->_valid && is_dir($this->_path)) {
>                 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->_field_name]['tmp_name'],
> $this->_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->_new_name)) {
>                     return true;
>                 }
>                 return false;
>             }
>             return false;
>         }
> 
>         public function getErrorMessage() {
>             if(!empty($this->_error)) {
>                 return $this->_validation[$this->_error];
>             }
>         }
>     }
```

Comment: Anyone could help me ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. "It doesn't work" is quite difficult to answer. What exactly is the problem? Also, I'd suggest you to use PHP formatting for your question. (```php ... ```)

Comment: The validation method return false when I try to uplaod an image

Comment: If you mean the `isValid()` method, in this case, your `$out` and therefore `$message` should contain a string denoting the concrete error. If this is not the case, your `$_FILES` array might be empty. I would go ahead and add some debug messages to that method to find out where exactly the `false` comes from.